# Firebug showing a failed attempt at loading .swd

Tags: flash, firebug, swfobject, fusioncharts

The product I work on deals heavily with graphs (mainly from FusionCharts). I use firebug extensively, and one of the little niggling problems that persists is every time a flash graph goes to load, I get an error. Let's say the flash object is titled `Column2D.swf`, that object loads just fine, but I always get a `404 not found` on an object called `Column2D.swd`. I know that this is a debug file, but since I don't make or manage any of the flash objects I don't know why this debug file is always called. On top of that, I seem to be one of the few of our devs that always see this issue. Is there any way to make it go away?

Thanks

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://blah.blahblah.com/websmart/smartcharts/v3/Column2D.swd"

Comment: I know the error is because something is searching for the .swd file, and it doesn't exist. But is this because some debug parameter is set in the .swf or elsewhere? Is it something that needs to be changed by FusionCharts?

Comment: Thanks, and if that is the case... I may just have to live with it. The swfs are created by FusionCharts, then they are manipulated by a company that makes our "WebSmart" IDE, and we don't have development rights to manipulate the swfs, just use them... Thanks again. Too bad I cannot flag you as the answer.

Comment: Hey... could you please answer the following: (1) What version of FusionCharts are you using, (2) Are you using it in Flex Application? (3) Could you somehow provide me a live URL where the problem exists?

Comment: (1)Our pages are made with this WebSmart ILE product. They repackage and license out FusionCharts as their own "SmartCharts". So it is always 1-2 release behind the latest FusionCharts. I only know that they are originally FusionCharts because that is what tech support has told me. Thus I don't have an exact version.

(2)Nope, no flex, the [WebSmart ILE](http://www.bcdsoftware.com/iseries400solutions/websmart/)

(3)I wish I could provide a url, but the only pages that I can bring up with this problem are apart of our subscription service.

I am very annoyed that I cannot give you further info.

Comment: If WebSmart ILE has re-compiled the charts, it might be some debug code they have added. From their site, it is not clear whether they are using FusionCharts FREE or redistributing commercial FusionCharts. A screenshot of a chart may help to identify and proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the fix to this. For some reason I had installed the "Debugger" version of Flash Player, thus it always wanted the `.swd` file in order to proceed with debugging. After I did a full uninstall of Flash from the system, and used the regular player, I no longer get the little `404 errors` looking for the `.swd`.